How can I avoid double quotes when copying from google sheets cell?
If I use this forumla:
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(13), 1, FILTER(F2:F, F2:F <> ""))

I will get this output:
52048663606
52010984909
62194569546

However, using this formula:
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(13), 1, FILTER("1" & CHAR(9) & "1" & CHAR(9) & F2:F, F2:F <> ""))

I get this output with double quotes, when copying and pasting it elsewhere:
"1  1   52048663606
1   1   52010984909
1   1   62194569546"

Do note that these quotes are not present in the cell itself, but only when it's copied(and pasted elsewhere).
How can I avoid that?
spreadsheet example here

So the reason why your formula produces that is because you have spaces in between the numbers which makes it a String or a Text. A text will always be represented with "Text". What you need to do is adjust your expected result as something that will be a valid number to remove the " ". Please let me know if this makes sense for you

hmm im not sure i understand, look at this: https://prnt.sc/s2AOp0iGFx4W, as you can see, it works fine as long as i dont have the tab character

Yes, exactly because the tab character doesn't exist in numbers. If the result of the formula falls as a valid number format it will not be pasted with " ".

but in my last screenshot example, the format is text, not number - then it works fine without " ". it is only with the tab character that " " comes. not otherwise if i use a text format, number format or a combination

I tried both formulas and couldn't get your results. But when I changed "Char(13)=> Char(10), I got the expected results AND no double quotes on the second formula. 1) What browser are you using?  2) The snapshot in your comments looks nothing like Google Sheets. Would you please edit the question to include a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Tedinoz thanks for response. i use vivaldi (which is based on chromium). i copied the result from gsheet and pasted it in windows' notepad. i have now edited the question to include a reproducible example.

btw just to add, i never have any double quotes for numbers or text or a combination of both, until now when i started using a tab character Char(13). i could get around it by adding a bunch of spaces instead of Char(13), but this would ultimately not be a treated as a real space and thus would not separate the output in columns.

and to clarify, the goal here is to COPY the result and PASTE IT OUTSIDE OF GSHEET. don't just look at the one-line output shown in ghseet lol

Are you saying that you want to prepend some (in this case, two) columns to the copied data?

@AndrewMorton so i already have D2:F7 in my example that i can copy from and it's all good. but i want to simplify it even further by getting D2:F7 into one cell that when copied, i can paste it WITHOUT double quotes. i only get double quotes if i use Char(13)

Go through the post threads linked here and try your luck to see if one or other suggestion works out for you!

Issue:
Unicode 13/Carriage Return(\r) and Unicode 10/Line feed(\n) is used as row separators and Unicode 9/Horizontal tab(\t) is used as column separator, when storing data in clipboard. You should note that in the clipboard, all data is stored raw without actual visual breaks. For eg, if A1:A3 has
52048663606
52010984909
62194569546

is just stored as 52048663606\n52010984909\n62194569546. If this data is pasted in another cell, Google sheets knows to use \n to separate this data into 3 rows. The same goes for  horizontal tabs \t.
However, what if \n and \t shouldn't be interpreted as separated rows or columns? What if 52048663606\n52010984909\n62194569546 is not 3 rows, but 1 cell? Google uses double quotes " to specify  that anything between these quotes shouldn't be separated, i.e. in this case, "52048663606\n52010984909\n62194569546".
Google seems to use it's own proprietory mime type format application/x-vnd.google-docs-spreadsheet-table+json(with alternative text/html and text/plain), which also might have other algorithms for separation. There also seems to be browser/device variations on the separators. But the above should hold for almost all.
Solution:
I don't believe you can avoid it, when using inbuilt CTRLC, when a cell is only selected. However, you may be able to enter edit mode in a cell by ENTER. Select using CTRLA or with the mouse and copy the raw data in edit mode. Alternatively, use any of the other whitespace characters
=LET(
  sp, UNICHAR(8192),
  lf, UNICHAR(11),
  TEXTJOIN(lf, 1, FILTER("1" & sp & "1" & sp & F2:F, F2:F <> ""))
)

In your final copy pasted text, in the final application, change the text back using regex.
